# How to use $link for watchdog messages in drupal?

Tags: drupal, hyperlink, drupal-7

I tried using l()

```
watchdog('my_module', 'My message for /admin/reports/dblog', WATCHDOG_NOTICE, 
$link = l(t('A hyperlink'), 
'/node/386/group?realname=&uid=&state=All&order=created&sort=desc', 
array('attributes'=>array('target'=>'blank'))) );
```

but the hyperlink is encoded "node/386/group%3Frealname%3D%26uid%3D%26state%3DAll%26order%3Dcreated%26sort%3Ddesc" which I understand is because **l()** is supposed to generate urls from drupal paths.

**Can I decode it before it's rendered or what's the proper way of inserting that hyperlink?**

Answer (score 0):

You should use query key for generating the path as shown below

```
<?php
global $base_url;
    print l(
      '', 
      $base_url . $node_url, 
        array(
          'attributes' => array(
            'id' => 'my-id', 
            'class' => 'my-class'
          ), 
          'query' => array(
            'foo' => 'bar'
          ), 
          'fragment' => 'refresh',
          'html' => TRUE
        )
    );
?>
```

This will generate a link like

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/node/1?foo=bar#refresh" id="my-id" class="my-class"><img src="http://www.example.com/files/image.jpg"/></a>
```

Source: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7.x

Comment: Thanks, should I be able to paste the whole url string into the query array to render the rest of the url **realname=&uid=&state=All&order=created&sort=desc** ?

`global $base_url;
print l('A hyperlink', $base_url . $node_url, 
array('query' => array('realname' => '&uid=&state=All&order=created&sort=desc')
)
);`

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
$link = l(t('A hyperlink'), '/node/386/group', array('attributes'=>array('target'=>'blank'))));
watchdog('my_module', 'Link !field_link.', array('!field_link' => $link));
```

Comment: Thanks, the goal though was to render the full url ending with **"?realname=&uid=&state=All&order=created&sort=desc"** which opens the group members sorted by created desc :) Any way around this or how I can pass these parameters on?